# Prove that $\inf \left(f(x) +g(x)\right) \ge \inf f(x) + \inf g(x)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I am confused on how to prove this.  I think I need an $x\in D$ for some $D$, because I've seen a lot of similar proofs do this.  Other than that I am lost, any direction would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For ALL $x\in D$,
$$\inf_{D} f\leq f(x)\mbox{ and } \inf_{D} g\leq g(x)\Rightarrow 
\inf_{D} f  +\inf_{D} g\leq f(x)+g(x)$$
which implies 
$$\inf_{D} f  +\inf_{D} g\leq \inf_D(f+g)$$
where in the last step we used the property that if $y\geq b$ for all $y\in Y$ then $\inf Y\geq b$ (recall the definition and the main properties of the [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition)).

Comment: First, thank you!  If y≥b for all y∈Y then inf Y≥b makes sense to me.  However, where does this apply to the f(x) and g(x)? is the b= inf (f) + inf(g) and the y=f(x)+g(x)? Because then I would fully understand. thank you again!

Comment: @ViciousCritter Yes, in the last step $Y$ is the set $(f+g)(D)=\{f(x)+g(x):x\in D\}$ and $b$ is the real number $\inf_{D} f  +\inf_{D} g$.